# Select max width of two controls and assign it to both of them in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, binding, silverlight-4.0, user-controls, width

I have 2 controls, each of them has dynamic content, so their width is set to auto.
But I want to align them and I need to link their widths in some way.

So for ex, Control_1 has width auto. After Loaded event its size become 200. Another Cotnrol_2 becomes 250. And I need first control to adjust its width to 250.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you two-way bind the width properties to properties of ViewModel. This way if one width property changes, depending on its value you can change the width of the other property and it will be reflected in the control.

Comment: As Luke Woodward said - control won't change Width property to something different than 'Auto' and ActualWidth is not a DP.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this kind of thing by handling the [SizeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged(v=vs.95).aspx) event on your two controls.  I'd wire this event on both controls to an event handler such as the following:

```
void ControlAOrB_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    double maxWidth = Math.Max(controlA.ActualWidth, controlB.ActualWidth);
    controlA.Width = maxWidth;
    controlB.Width = maxWidth;
}
```

I haven't tested this code, so I don't know whether setting the `Width` of a control to the width it already has will cause another SizeChanged event to fire, invoke this event handler again and hence cause infinite recursion.  It might therefore be an idea to only set the control's width to `maxWidth` if it's currently less than `maxWidth`.

I don't think an approach using binding works particularly well here.  The [`ActualWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth(v=vs.95).aspx) property of a FrameworkElement returns the actual width that the control has been rendered with, but you can't bind to `ActualWidth` because it isn't a dependency property.

Comment: I don't like that solution, it looks as dirty hack to me. In addition I'm trying to set Width property of children of these control, so I have to either rethrow event or something else.